# NoSuchMethodError, function name has been changed

Tags: kotlin, ethereum, nosuchmethoderror

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.math.BigInteger
> org.kethereum.model.ECKeyPair.getPrivateKey-V6oYYD4()'

I'm using an KEthereum library in my project and when call a method **.getPrivateKey()**, there's this strange random string **-V6oYYD4** added to original function. I haven't encountered this type of issue before.

Original function name: **.getPrivateKey()**

Modified function name: **.getPrivateKey-V6oYYD4()**

Function is calling from Unit Test. I'm using Kotlin.

Executing line of code is

```kotlin
val seed: org.kethereum.bip32.model.Seed = MnemonicWords(VALID_MNEMONIC_15).toSeed()
val actualPrivateKey: String = seed.toKey("m/").keyPair.privateKey.key.toString()
```

Edit: **Solved! The issue was somewhere else.** I've look at [test file of the library](https://github.com/komputing/KEthereum/blob/master/bip32/src/test/kotlin/org/kethereum/bip32/DerivationTest.kt) and I realized I have to serialize the ExtendedKey first. So I did that, my code looks like this:

```kotlin
val seed: org.kethereum.bip32.model.Seed = MnemonicWords(VALID_MNEMONIC_15).toSeed()
val derivedKey = seed.toKey("m/")
assertThat(derivedKey.serialize()).isEqualTo(XPRV_OF_MNEMONIC_15)
```

and everything works now.

The extra string at the end is probably from compiled JVM code.

Comment: Could the extra string be how the Kotlin compiler implements `internal` functions, deliberately obfuscating the name so they can't be called from outside the module?

Comment: @gidds definitely could be. Later I realized that more other functions have some postfix too.